# calling node js api from codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, curl

i have downloaded curl library from git hub and saved it at proper path, api written in node produces result when i check on postman but when i call from my controller it returns bool('false')

```
<?php
class login extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('Curl');
    }
    public function api_call()
    {
        //echo "danish";exit;
        $result = $this->curl->simple_get('80.100.200.80:7060/abc/xyz?sort=createdAt&page=1&limit=20');
        var_dump($result);
    }
}
?>
```

please help

Comment: try codeigniter documentation.....                                                       $this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');
$query = $this->db->get();                                                                                        https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=joins#selecting-data

Comment: But I don't see any $query variable in the code you posted...please post full part of the code

Comment: that is just and example.... $query is the name of a variable just like you have $Data in your code...... if you haven't declared it before it would obviously show that $query is unknown